# Type 'this[K]' is not assignable to type 'NonNullable<this[K]>'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I don't understand why typescript is throwing an error for this:

```
public saveGet<K extends keyof this> (key: K, def: NonNullable<this[K]>): NonNullable<this[K]> {
    if (this[key] !== null && this[key] !== undefined) {
      return this[key]
    } else {
      return def
    }
  }
```

error:

```
Type 'this[K]' is not assignable to type 'NonNullable<this[K]>'.
  Type 'this[keyof this]' is not assignable to type 'NonNullable<this[K]>'.
    Type 'this[string] | this[number] | this[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'NonNullable<this[K]>'.
      Type 'this[string]' is not assignable to type 'NonNullable<this[K]>'.ts(2322)
```

As far as i understand, the typescript compiler should be able to rule out `null` and `undefined` from `this[key]` (hence the comparison) and therefore I should be able to return it.

Could someone explain it?
I'm sorry if this was already asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue here is that the TypeScript compiler doesn't perform the sort of higher-order reasoning necessary to see when a value is assignable to a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depends on an as-yet unspecified [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter.  In your example code, you expect the compiler to use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to realize that `this[key]` should be narrowed from `this[K]` to `NonNullable<this[K]>`.  Unfortunately, both `K` and the [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) are unspecifed inside the body of `saveGet()`.  (`K` is obviously a generic parameter, but `this` is sort of a "virtual" generic parameter.  You don't have to declare it, but is acts like a parameter that is unspecified inside the class body and becomes specified when you have an instance of the class.)  And so the compiler doesn't know how to narrow the type of `this[key]`.  The canonical open issue about this is [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), which talks about the challenges involved in trying to address this in general.

The workaround here is probably to write a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to take control of the narrowing behavior.

---

A less important but still relevant issue is that the compiler does not do control-flow based narrowing of an object property when you use bracket index access; see [microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530) for more info.  So checking `this[key]` will unfortunately not do anything to subsequent checks of `this[key]`.  The workaround here is to assign `this[key]` to its own variable and check that.

---

This means the current workaround for your issue looks like this:

```
// user defined type guard function
function isNonNullable<T>(x: T): x is NonNullable<T> {
  return x !== null && x !== undefined
}

public saveGet<K extends keyof this>(
  key: K, def: NonNullable<this[K]>): NonNullable<this[K]> {
  const thisKey = this[key]; // save into own variable
  if (isNonNullable(thisKey)) {
    return thisKey; // okay now
  } else {
    return def
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgOQWkAbbBDAI2wFMAeAFQD4AKADwC5FyBKR25FRDMLXQkipUQBvALAAoRIgBOxKCGlJ2AQgC8qxGBzZEAMl2IV6xOAAmxYDDDFTEgL4SJEfCk4AxOHBGPJiAA4gRDAQiCh4AG7EAOJypADSiMS0UMRgppwA1sQAnnDAiFAAFqg0WdmMcQA0iObAjNy8+ERkRagA2nEAupSsXJja-C3FKB3d3r5SEAgoUAXDcTmIGq0jZZ0A3BJSUjD51KgNA83UKwvZzMzj29uy8opzqGebE4h2idgoxFfXMnIKSLUttsHL4QfYJEA)

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation!